# Complicated reports for huge amount of data in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, reporting

I'm using oracle 11g to store huge set of data (around 1kk records). My schema looks like (simplified):

Client table:

```
   ---------------------------------------
  |id | firstName | lastName | middleName |
   ---------------------------------------
```

Operation table:

```
   ---------------------------------------
  |id | client_id | date | balance | type |
   ---------------------------------------
```

And I need to generate filtered and agregeted report for client including different agregated rows. For example, I need a report with clients who have operations some type of operations. Report should contains colums like: sum of balance of all operations, sum of balance of operation with filtering type, sum of balance of operation in current year.

I'm generating a request using java and hibernate criteria, but the code grows and now it too dificult to maintain it.

What the best decision to generate complicated reports using sql:

1. Load all data to my application and agregate it in my code?
2. Split filtering and agregation logic into stored function?
3. Split filtering and agregation in steps using temporary tables?
4. Use 3rd party software or others nosql storage to generate reports? (like bi tools or map-reduce)
5. Write a java-stored procedure?

What is "standart enterprise" solution to generate complicated reports on huge amount of data with normal performance and resource utilization?

Comment: Common rule is: do most of your work in Oracle, not on your client software.  Huge SQL queries (1k+ lines) are normal in Oracle world :-)  But if you have found common part of two reports you should calculate it separately and, probably, save its result in intermediate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is not your friend in this situation. As a first step, try writing Oracle stored proc(s) and calling them from Java via JDBC or via Hibernate, if the rest of your application is already using Hibernate.

If there are common parts of your calculation, consider breaking them out into separate stored procs.

If there is common data that changes relatively slow (compared to the rest of the data), you can use materialized views.

Another consideration. If you are doing a lot of reporting by dates, but the Operations table records are timestamped with a date/time field, consider adding a numeric field for the calendar dates in the format, say 20130315, and index on it. This would go long ways toward the performance improvement, but might still leave you with huge Oracle queries.

How big is your data again? What is "1kk"?

Comment: With 1M records you definitely would not what to load them all in memory and do calculations in Java. For Oracle is no biggie, but whne you get to 1M records per month and with data retention requirements of, say, couple of years, you'd have to consider Oracle table partitioning. The numeric calendar id would come handy again at that point.